# Unable to create online web-page

Tags: go

I am trying to create Golang web-pages...

Progress:

1. Ubuntu 18.04 installed both locally and on a Linode VPS.
2. Created and compiled a local Golang "Hello World" script that renders OK both locally and online.
3. Created a net/http Golang script that works OK when called locally http://localhost:8080/testing to see if it works
4. Uploaded the script to the Linode server and initial status messages appear but when calling http:123.456.789.32:8080/testing to see if it works the browser freezes.

```
//
// Golang - main.go
//
package main

import (
  "net/http"
)

func sayHello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  message := r.URL.Path
  message = "Hello " + message

  w.Write([]byte(message))
}

func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("/", sayHello)

  if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
}
```

There are no errors or warnings rendered and unable to find any log references.

Can error and warnings similar to PHP error_reporting(-1), declare(strict_types=1) etc be logged or rendered?

Comment: No way to check your server logs?

Comment: Access your endpoint via curl with -v or --trace (or --trace-ascii) to see clearer what's going on.

Comment: Go doesn't have errors and warnings. At compile time there are only errors and at runtime there are only panics. Neither can be disabled; they always indicate really serious errors. Other than that the program outputs only what you tell it to. Don't get into the habit of "handling" errors with `panic`. That should be reserved for programming errors.

Comment: That really can have about a gazillion reasons. Do you have a firewall activated on your node? Is port 8080 open in it? Are you sitting behind a coporate firewall? Can you reach the server itself (via a ping, for example)? Do you use a proxy?

Comment: Try to omit the panic(err). Any difference? And omit the "testing" after port number

Comment: NEVER post real IP adresses or host/domain names. You can expect additional unwanted "visitors", trying to brute force into your ssh.

Comment: @sibert if it would panic, we would have more information. If it does not, removing it does not change a thing.

Comment: Uhm, have you actually compiled the "script" (Go is actually a compiled language) and are you running the result on the server?

Answer (score 1):

A quick check with Nmap showed this result:

```
nmap -sV -p 8080 <yourIP>
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-07-04 07:45 CEST
Nmap scan report for <your-domain>.com (<yourIP>)
Host is up (0.032s latency).

PORT     STATE    SERVICE    VERSION
8080/tcp filtered http-proxy

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.90 seconds
```

The state of "filtered" actually means that there was no response on that port as opposed to an outright rejection of the request.

Check the output of `iptables -L -n`. Presumably, you have a firewall running and blocking port 8080. Do **not** simply deactivate the firewall, but read up on how to open port 8080 in the firewall product you are using. Linode has [guides for the commonly used/preinstalled firewalls of various Linux distributions](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/firewalls/).

If you plan to go into production, *please* have someone help you to ensure security and availability of your deployment.

Comment: problem. The firewall has now been fixed.

I am most surprised that not one of the examples I tried suggested testing to see if the firewall was blocking the port especially since using Golang it only takes a couple of lines to ensure the port is open! 
I am tempted to suggest the modification to all that only supply the basic script.

Comment: @user2436802 Separation of concerns. Usually, a developer should not be required to deal with firewalls (or networking for that matter, unless the system in development is related to that). Personally I do not and would not check wether a port is reachable from within a server itself.

Comment: I am a full stack hobbyist therefore the concerns are not separate :) Server has about a dozen Apache2 web sites. I am looking forward to trying and comparing Golang with existing sites.

Comment: Still - you should not intermix the aspects. Good recipe for getting into trouble.